# Decode JSON response from API in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I am trying to decode a JSON response from a API and store "serial_no" as a string, below my codes, But i am unable get the expected result.Am i doing anything wrong

**JSON Response from API**

```
 [
        {
            "id": 20063,
            "transaction_date": "2020-01-24 10:41:031",
            "reference_id": "91",
            "voucher": [
                {
                    "serial_no": "KFCYQOqW23012024"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**PHP Code**

```
/* posting parameters to API */
$post = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
        'headers'     => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        'body' =>      $reserve_array 
    ) );
/*Decode JSON response to store in $serial */

 $result =  json_decode($post);
 $serial=$result[0]->voucher[0]->serial_no;
```

Comment: `$result[0]->voucher[0]->serial_no`?

Comment: @dibery i tried that, however $serial was null, PHP code updated FYR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below PHP code solved my issue

```
 $result =  json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $post) );
 $serial=$result[0]->voucher[0]->serial_no;
```